# Return type error in python

Tags: python

So I'm getting this error on a line where I have a recursive call. The line where the error occurred looks something like: `return some_func(x) - .2`

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'`

I tried `return some_func(x) - .2 and x not None and float(x) is True`, and other tricks but unsuccessfully so far.

Thanks!

Comment: How can you expect anyone to solve your problem, without seeing your code?

Comment: It's more than 300 line of codes. I thought I would just post the line I'm having problem with, and give you some background. Thanks.

Comment: Your `some_func(x)` is of 300 lines? You can just post the relevant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`some_func(x)` returns `None`, and you cannot subtract a float from `None`—that wouldn’t make any sense. Depending on your needs, you can either make sure `some_func(x)` never returns `None` (by changing the implementation of `some_func`), or do this:

```
y = some_func(x)
if y is not None:
    return y - .2
else:
    return None
```

The last two lines can be omitted, since functions in Python implicitly return `None`.

Comment: `y is not None` is the more pythonic test.

Comment: Or you can just use this on-liner: - `return y if y is None else y - .2`

Comment: BTW if function returns nothing (i.e. doesn't have a `return` statement), it also returns `None`

Comment: @RohitJain that is considered unreadable by some, but you’re right.

Comment: @daknøk. Why would that be unreadable. It just a `conditional expression` written that way in Python. Ignore the `return` and see rest of the code.. You can understand easily.

Comment: also this is enough: `return y - .2 if y is not None`

Comment: We can all list a thousand shorter ways to do this, but my point was to make the idea clear to the OP.

Comment: @etuardu, your solution doesn't seem to work. Thanks guys, my problem has been resolved.

Comment: @RohitJain, formally not, but [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, the error message seems to imply that at some point your function `some_func(x)` returns `None`. As the message states, you subtraction operation between `None` and the `float` is not possible in Python.

Trace your function and make sure that it always returns a numeric value and that problem should not occur. *Alternatively*, change your code to check the return for `None` (as shown by @daknok) and avoid the problem that way - however, it's better to prevent the problem at the source IMO.

Note the excellent comment by @burhan Kahlid below too.

Comment: Also note, if a function doesn't return anything, it will implicitly have a return value of `None`. So make sure all execution paths (like if statements) have explicit return statements.

Comment: Why is my condition on the return type not working then? I thought I could take care of it with a conditional return statement like I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your fix

```
return some_func(x) - .2 and x not None and float(x) is True
```

doesn't work for at least three reasons.

1. Python lazily evaluates `and`s.

   That is, `A and B` evaluates `A` first, then if `A` is true it evaluates `B`. In your case, evaluating `A` causes an exception, so you never even get to `B`.
2. The check for not being none is `x is not None`, not `x not None`.
3. The problem is that `some_func(x)` is `None`, not that `x` is `None`. Checking the latter is irrelevant.

---

Anyway, the solution is not to subtract floats from a value that may be `None`. The best way to do this is to ensure that `some_func` never returns `None`, which you can do by modifying its code. The next best is to check the return value, which you can do as

```
output = some_func(x)
if output is not None:
    return output - 0.2
```

Note, by the way, that if a function doesn't return anything then it is considered as implicitly returning `None`. So the above code will return `None` if `some_func` did. This may also be the source of your problem.